# Test iCloud backup restore with test App

Tags: ios, iphone, backup, icloud, restore

I am wondering if there is a way to test iCloud backup restore for a test app that has not yet been submittet to the app store.

Since iCloud backup only backs up app data and not the actual app (as opposed to local backup via iTunes), the restore fails in this case.

Is there any way to work around this issue for testing purposes?

Comment: I'd like to test the same... did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Yes, you can release the app to Testflight.

Comment: @Chry007 you gave me a big hint xD

Comment: @Chry007 Any luck?

Comment: @Nik Yes, you can release the app to Testflight, that works.